# Microsoft Test manager in iOS Environment?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

The issue is that we use iOS desktop machines within testing department and we want to use MTM as a test management tool. Is there any way for this to be achieved?? (Apart from changing the machines to windows) We do have windows server within our agency where MTM can be installed.

I was thinking along the lines of having it installed on a Windows based server and then accessing it from iOS devices using firefox/Chrome. However I am not sure if this can be done.

Comment: What version of Team Foundation Server is behind MTM?

Comment: At this stage we havnt got TFS but we will be looking to purchase that... I am trying to identify if this can be achieved.. If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFS 2012.2 or higher you can use the Web Access test tools to run the test runner from a browser.

Here's a quick video of what it looks like with TFS 2013 as the backend.

http://blog.nwcadence.com/whats-new-in-team-foundation-server-2013-online-test-plansuite-management/

If you're considering purchasing TFS, I'd recommend starting with 2013 even though it is in preview. We've installed it in quite a few production environments, and it is fully supported by MS (it is "go live").

You'll still need MTM installed on a Windows box somewhere if you want to do detailed test plan configuration, and some other advanced features. You'll also lose the ability to use any data collectors if you're using the web-based test runner.

EDIT:

1) Lots. You won't be accessing MTM from the internet. MTM is a desktop application. You'll have access to an online test runner (completely different from MTM) that will use TFS as the backend for work item tracking. This means that most of the features won't be accessible. Things like action recordings and exploratory testing.

2) Totally depends on number of users, load, etc. Check out the documentation for that. In general, < 100 users you need two machines about 2 core 8gb each unless you want a sharepoint server.

3) It isn't MTM. It is an online test runner. I've used it in Chrome, Firefox and IE without trouble.

4) License questions are out of scope for SO. Typically one purchases MSDN subscriptions for users. Contact a MS salesperson if you need more information along these lines.

Comment: Ok, That takes me to my next set of ques.
1. Apart from Data collectors, any other features that we lose using web based test runner?
2. What are the minimum system server requirements for TFS to be installed?
3. Considering some of us will be accessing MTM from iOS desktop, Will MTM be accessible from Firefox/Chrome/Safari?
4. I am also not sure how its licenses are sold?
  a. is it just one piece of software sold to Orgs and as many people within the Org can use it or is it sold based on number of people within the organisation require access?
  b. Any trial periods are offered?

Answer (score 0):

This can now be accomplished if you have Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 or Visual Studio Test Professional You can now run Microsoft Test Manager online application via the browser as part of Team Foundation Server or Visual Studio Team Services!

With Visual Studio Team Services all the functionality of Microsoft Test Manager is built into the cloud and accessible via web-browser so there is no need for the stand-alone windows application. The only additional functionality of the stand-alone windows application is the ability to record video of test case steps. You can add test cases in the web browser under Project > Test > Test Plans.

Here is the Visual Studio Product Pricing Breakdown from Microsoft:
[image: Visual Studio Product Pricing Breakdown from Microsoft]

Here is a screenshot of Test Manager Online App in TFS:
[image: Test Manager in TFS]